# ¿Cómo puedo limitar el resultado en ListAPIView después de un filtro?

Tags: python, djangorestframework

Tengo este código para la vista del libro de lista, pero quiero limitar los resultados de ListAPIView, he usado un FilterSet para el filtrado.
Mi pregunta es ¿hay otra forma de hacerlo sin sobrescribir el método list de ListAPIView?

```py
class ListBooksAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    filter_class = BookFilter

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        filter_last = self.request.query_params.get('filter_last')
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        if filter_last:
            queryset = queryset[:int(filter_last)]
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```